# permanent redirect query in htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, redirect

i am trying to create a redirect from `non` `www` to the `www` version of my website

i want to redirect `http://abc.pk/` to `http://www.abc.pk/`  but my query tbut not working properly

here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed on 
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
</IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /JobScholar/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @TimBrownlaw how can you say its a duplicate question without reading it. i do the same [rocess but redirect not working maybe some hierarchy issue of writing queries.

Comment: Ok I have withdrawn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version for you to try...

Taken from a link of one of many SOF answers, you said wasn't a duplicate of your question.

START with this before adding in everything else you have and test it.

I've run it through the hoops on my system and deliberately broke things to make sure everything was running...

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect all non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```